# Power Automate (Microsoft Flow) embedded in Power Apps Model-driven Apps / Dynamics 365 is not triggering

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-modeldriven

Has anyone successfully embedded Power Automate in Power Apps Model-driven Apps / Dynamics 365? After clicking the "Run flow" button the process is not triggered, only the "Login Successful" message appears. Could somebody help?
[image: "Run flow" button and "Login successful" message]

Comment: Can you share the details on how you have embedded the flow, have you created a CDS flow button?

Comment: First of all, suddenly the flow started running properly. However, we still don't know what the problem was. Answering your question, the flow is created in solution and embeeded as a Business Process Flow step, like here: https://www.inogic.com/blog/2020/03/power-automate-flows-now-available-from-within-business-process-flows/